# which accesses does 'youtubepartner' scope grant in youtube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The documentation seems unclear.
It says "View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube". What does "asset" refer to ?

This is a common enough question that I thought it should be answered, though.

Answer (score 0):

An asset resource represents a piece of intellectual property, such as a sound recording or television episode.

Comment: So, my original question stays, which is what permissions are you authorizing when you give "youtubepartner" permission to an application?